# How to connect a Galaxy Tab 4 to projector with VGA or HDMI?

Tags: hdmi, samsung-galaxy-tab-4, mhl

I have a Galaxy Tab 4 10.1 (SM-T531) that I want to connect to a projector. So far as I have checked, there is no working MHL adapter for it.

Could someone please tell me another way to connect it either with HDMI or VGA wirelessly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use [Amazon Fire TV](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00U3FPN4U) and the [Amazon Fire Stick](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00GDQ0RMG) with my Galaxy Tab 4 7.0 and Galaxy S3. The [Microsoft Wireless Display Adapter](https://www.microsoft.com/hardware/en-us/p/wireless-display-adapter) is supposed to work with Android devices as well. All of these options connect to an HDMI port.

The Fire Stick is by far the most cost effective route and is very easy to use. Here is how to use display mirroring on the Fire TV and Stick (from Amazon's website):

> To quickly start display mirroring, on your Amazon Fire TV remote
>   press and hold the Home button and select Mirroring. Then connect your
>   compatible device. Swipe down from the top of the screen to open Quick
>   Settings, and then tap Settings. Tap Display & Sounds, and then tap
>   Display Mirroring.

Comment: Will it also work with a projector?

Comment: The Amazon Fire Stick plugs directly into a HDMI port while the Amazon Fire TV uses a separate HDMI cable. As long as your projector has an HDMI input it should work perfectly.